# Random Green Dot In Screen

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, 3d-view

New to Blender 2.9.
How do I remove this green dot, which appears in object mode and renders preview?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the Origin of the last selected object, if it's really annoying you can remove it from the viewport overlay menu on the bottom right in your case.
[image: Viewport overlay]